# Hiding files of a certain extension (.pyc) from Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, file-extension, nautilus

I would like to hide every .pyc file from Nautilus. 
I use Ubuntu 10.04.

What could I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a completely different problem which has nothing to do with hiding files at all.

Comment: "rm -r *.pyc" would "hide" all those pesky files and free up some space at the same time.  Pity they'd reappear next time you ran the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to not create these files at all. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files

You can also quickly delete these files from Nautilus by pressing `ctrl+s`, entering `*.pyc` pattern and hitting `delete` key.

Answer (score 10):

Just need to open a bash terminal and run:

> ls *.py[co] >> .hidden

bingo!

Answer (score 5):

You can add all the .pyc filenames to a `.hidden` file in the same directory.  Requires some maintenance, but if you're like me you do a lot more modifying of existing files than creating new ones.

Comment: Does this work on Mac OS or only Linux ?

Answer (score -1):

I have read all the answers under this question and created a simple script to automate the task:

https://github.com/neatsoft/nautilus-hide-pyc

It allows to hide temporary Python files in the GNOME Files (Nautilus). Searches for the pyc/pyo files recursively and puts it to the .hidden files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hide() {
  for d in *.py[co]; do
    if [ -f "$d" ]; then
      echo $d
    fi
  done | tee "$(pwd)/.hidden" > /dev/null
}

recursive() {
  for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
      (cd -- "$d" && hide)
      (cd -- "$d" && recursive)
    fi
  done
}

(recursive)
```